# Jquery hover fadeIn/fadeOut problem

Tags: jquery, fade

http://www.izrada-weba.com/orso
On mouseover on link "NENATKRIVENA TERASA..." submenu and image fade in together. Submenu is faded using some downloaded script and image above is fading using my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#slika1").hide();

  $("#test,#submenu2").hover(
      function () {
       $("#slika1").fadeIn();
      }, 
      function () {
         $("#slika1").fadeOut();
      }
    );       
});
```

When mouse is over link than image fades in, and when mouse is moved to submenu image fades out and than fades in again... I know why is that so but I don't know how to make it not fadeout when moving mouse directly from link to submenu.
Are there any solutions for this?

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function stop() will stop any currently running animations on the specified element.
Try modifying your mouseover function:

```
$("#slika1").stop().fadeIn();
```

**Edit:**
There seems to be a problem with the submenu not fading in all the way (see ile's comment).  This seems to me like its a jQuery bug, but I'm not sure.  Maybe someone can chime in and explain why this is happening.
To get around this try using fadeTo(); it seems to produce the desired result:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#slika1").fadeTo(0,0);

  $("#test,#submenu2").hover(
    function () {
      $("#slika1").stop(true).fadeTo("normal",1);
    }, 
    function () {
      $("#slika1").fadeTo("normal",0);
    }
  );       
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, there is new problem occurring now, when moving mouse fast from link to submenu image doesn't fade in 100% and then image stays transparent even if I make moseouver again :/

Comment: If a jQuery fadeOut event is interupted with a stop the fadeIn event will only go as far as the opacity it had when the stop event was called. This seems like a bug, +1 though for the fadeTo workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `fadeIn()` not working when the `fadeOut()` is interrupted is because `fadeIn()` only works if the element is hidden. Whether you call it a bug or a feature. To remedy this you can do the following.

```
$("#mydiv").stop().hide().fadeIn(450);
```