# Suggestions for using this simple jQuery fadeOut() example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

Basically, when someone mouses over their shopping cart summary I want to display a div containing more detailed information.

Here is a working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JgZp/

**Javascript**

```
    $('#shopping-cart').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeIn();
    });

    $('#shopping-cart').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeOut();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="user-information">
    <div id="shopping-cart">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/shoppingcart.png")" alt="shopping cart" />
        <p>Products in Shopping Cart: <span class="cart-item-count">2</span> <span class="cart-subtotal">(<span class="cart-subtotal-value">25,54</span>$)</span></p>

        <div id="shopping-cart-preview">
            <p>This is a test.</p>
            <p>This is a test.</p>
            <p>This is a test.</p>
            <p>This is a test.</p>
            <p>This is a test.</p>
            <p>This is a test.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="action-buttons">
        <a class="loginbutton" href="#">LOGIN</a>
        <a class="registerbutton" href="#">REGISTER</a>
    </div>
</div>

#user-information #shopping-cart {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**CSS**

```
#user-information #shopping-cart img {
    float: left;
}

#user-information #shopping-cart p {
    color: White;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#user-information #shopping-cart p span.cart-subtotal {
    color: #CFE91A;
    margin-left: 11px;
}

#user-information #shopping-cart #shopping-cart-preview {
    background-color: White;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    outline: 1px solid cyan;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    width: 320px;
}

#user-information #shopping-cart #shopping-cart-preview p {
    margin: 0;
    color: Black;
}

#user-information #action-buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

The JSFiddle example works exactly how I want it to with the exception that when I move the mouse from the cart summary to the cart preview pane that pops up, the fadeOut() event is fired then immidiately the fadeIn() event is fired. So we get that fadeout fadein dilemma.

I'd like the pane to not dissapear when I move the mouse down to enter the summary.

What do you suggest?

Another problem is that when I move the mouse in and out quickly, it seems the animations are queued and executed. This means that the element might fadein/out many many times even after I'm done moving the mouse. Suggestions?

---

**EDIT**:

So I'm trying something like this; "Hide the preview if they clicked outside of it."

```
$('#wrapper').click(function () {
    if ($(this) != $('#shopping-cart')) {
        $('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeOut();    
    }
});
```

However, even when I click inside the preview, the fadeOut() called is invoked. I'm sure something is wrong with my conditional statement. Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT 2:**

Figure it out with some ideas from you guys. :)

Here's how you do it:

```
$('#shopping-cart').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#shopping-cart-preview').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});

$('#shopping-cart').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#shopping-cart-preview').delay(2000).fadeOut();
});

$('#shopping-cart-preview').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
```

Comment: +1 for a great question and some nice written code but -1 for the terrible and unformated fiddle :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery hover fadeIn/fadeOut problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652747/jquery-hover-fadein-fadeout-problem)

Comment: `$.stop(true)` might be just what you´re looking for! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, not sure if it´s enough but please give it a try;

```
$('#shopping-cart')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeIn();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#shopping-cart-preview').delay(500).fadeOut();
    });

$('#shopping-cart-preview').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).delay(500).fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Well what do you know, this solved the issue 100% the way I wanted it to. Clean code, no external dependencies to libs, it's just a great solution. Thanks for your help. :) I didn't know you could .delay() animations! However, there is still a problem, if you move the mouse in and out of the event landing area, the preview div eventually bugs out. :/

Comment: read up on jquery queue (http://api.jquery.com/queue/). I believe that would fix the 'eventually bugs out' problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on navigation for thecl.com

My solution was to use http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html , it gives a delay allowing the user to mouse in the div which keeps it open.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgZp/19/)**

The change is in the Jquery code:

```
$('#shopping-cart').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#shopping-cart-preview').stop().fadeIn();
});
$('#shopping-cart').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeOut();
});
```

Also, I would recommending having the Shopping cart preview div appear right under the shopping cart summary div. This will eliminate the problem of losing the preview div if a user is slow in moving his mouse from the summary div to the preview div. I don't suppose anyone would be that slow, though.

EDIT:

**[New Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgZp/21/)**

The user can now be slow in moving from the summary div to the preview div. There is not a timeout that does not trigger the fadeout until after 1 sec of mouseleave. You can change the 1 sec to anything else.

New Code:

```
$('#shopping-cart').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#shopping-cart-preview').stop().fadeIn();
});
$('#shopping-cart').mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#shopping-cart-preview').fadeOut();},1000);
});
```

Comment: Try moving the mouse over the `#shopping-cart` div many many times. It eventually bugs out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this - I've moved the shopping cart preview div outside of the shopping cart div, and simplified the jquery code -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgZp/15/)

Comment: In your fiddle, hovering over the shopping cart preview div makes it disappear. I think that would not be favorable if you provide links in that div. They would not be clickable

Comment: This still has the same problem.

Comment: @xbonez: Yes, in fact. I'll be adding a link to checkout inside this preview div, so it has to remain open and allow people to click inside of it.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. What about using a tooltip plugin like [Qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) for this?

Comment: Or the pre-release 1.9 jQuery UI tooltip library.  The 1.9 milestone that introduced the tooltip has been out for 1.5 years, so it might be a bit more stable by now (?).  http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/05/jquery-ui-19m1-tooltip/ - you can probably get the latest 1.9 milestone and it will contain the tooltip widget.